# Rails 3.2 - can't precompile assets

Tags: asset-pipeline, assets, ruby-on-rails-3.2, precompile

I am trying to precompile assets (`rake assets:precompile` or `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`), but I always get the error

```
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/b...]

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Has anybody an idea what could be wrong?

**EDIT** trace output

```
rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:277:in `new_connection'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:287:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:235:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `loop'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `block in checkout'
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `checkout'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__1002303312927586119__prepare__1187908839264703097__callbacks'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/adam/rubydev/aivloo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:89:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/b...]
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of the command with `--trace`? What happens if you run it with superuser privileges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a wrong password/username combination for your MySQL database. There are some gems that "need" database access for asset precompilation, to turn this off, check [this question for Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430578/how-to-universally-skip-database-touches-when-precompiling-assets-on-heroku).

Answer (score 9):

Not your issue, but if a Google search brings someone else here (as it did me) make sure you're specifying what RAILS_ENV you're in:

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development`

I was running a precompile test in development and kept getting this error until I remembered to put the environment.

Comment: this just saved me a lot of debugging